# Boost C++ - Entry points?

Tags: c++, boost, program-entry-point, entry-point, winmain

Basically I moved on from the main() entry point in my project and changed to a windows project - WINAPI WinMain(...)

However Boost complains saying that cpp_main() is missing.
How can I avoid this?
Thanks.

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: There's nothing to post. I just have the WINAPI WinMain() function and linked + included the headers for boost. On compile time - it mentions that cpp_main() is missing (which I use is int main()).

Comment: Try keeping it as `int main()` (and telling the linker off if it complains about that).

Comment: There's no such thing as "linked and included the headers for boost."  Boost is a large selection of libraries that all behave in their own way and have their own requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you work in MS Visual Studio, create Win32Project, then use WinMain() function.
If you create Console application, then use main() function.
Nothing to do with boost library.

Answer (score 0):

It's `Boost.Test` library that needs a special user-defined entry point. Please, read [its manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/test/doc/html/prg-exec-monitor.html) for details.